# Enumerate console parameters (argv) in CMake

Tags: cmake, argv, argc

I want to parse/process passed console parameters in CMake, so that if I run this in console:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSOME_FLAG=1 ..
```

I want to obtain the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and `-DSOME_FLAG=1` from this inside CMake script (and every other parameter passed) and save them somewhere.

The reason I want it is to pass all parameters through custom CMake script (which calls `execute_process(cmake <something>)` after) e.g.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -P myscript.cmake
```

Comment: Good question (and answer). But why would you want to do this? It is very uncommon to encounter CMakeLists which can deal with any parameters and probably won't work with CMake-GUI.

Comment: Thanks. I did it because I wanted to pass all parameters through custom CMake script (which calls `execute_process(cmake <something>)` after) e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -P myscript.cmake`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `CMAKE_ARGC` variable which contains amount of variables passed to CMake (divided by whitespaces), and `CMAKE_ARGV0`, `CMAKE_ARGV1`, ... which contains actual values.

It's common for languages for C++ that first (zero) variable holds the command you called (`cmake` in this situation), so we will need everything except `CMAKE_ARGV0`. Let's make a simple loop then:

```
set(PASSED_PARAMETERS "") # it will contain all params string
set(ARG_NUM 1) # current index, starting with 1 (0 ignored)

# you can subtract something from that if you want to ignore some last variables
# using "${CMAKE_ARGC}-1" for example 
math(EXPR ARGC_COUNT "${CMAKE_ARGC}") 

while(ARG_NUM LESS ARGC_COUNT)
    # making current arg named "CMAKE_ARGV" + "CURRENT_INDEX"
    # in CMake like in Bash it's easy
    set(CURRENT_ARG ${CMAKE_ARGV${ARG_NUM}}) 

    message(STATUS "Doing whatever with ${CURRENT_ARG}")  

    # adding current param to the list
    set(PASSED_PARAMETERS ${PASSED_PARAMETERS} ${CURRENT_ARG})        

    math(EXPR ARG_NUM "${ARG_NUM}+1") # incrementing current index
endwhile()
```

(Answering my own question, didn't find anything like that in SO, maybe it'll help someone)